# Couldn't load QGIS utils; Python support disabled; No module named future

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, installation, python-2.7

Unexpectedly Qgis won't open today. Error code is:

```
Couldn't load QGIS utils.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 20, in 
    from future import standard_library
ImportError: No module named future

Python version:
2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

QGIS version: 2.15.0-Master 'Master', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/simon/.qgis2/python', u'/home/simon/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

I've done some digging around similar errors to no avail. `utils.py` imports a module from `__future__` successfully then `standard_library` from `future` unsuccessfully. [This](http://python-future.org/reference.html) suggests that future/standard_library should work though. I've just reinstalled (xubuntu, debian nightly ppa) and still no joy. Qgis has been working fine until now, although I've not opened it for about a month or so. Searching for `future` in `/usr/lib` doesn't give any other exact matches: `futures.py` in `/python3.4/asyncio`, `fix.future.py` in `python3.4/lib2to3/fixes`, the same file in python2.7 folder...

2.7 isn't new, so 2.7's `future` has assumedly never had `standard_library` in it, right? What am I missing here? Could an independent package have decided I no longer need a more recent version of python, I okayed it for autoremove, and it turns out Qgis needs that version of python's `future`?

OS is xubuntu 15.10

Comment: is there now some code on stackexchange which autodeletes "Hi all" if I put it at the start? Feels nice to open with something friendly rather than dive right into "help me"...

Comment: I believe so as this was discussed here: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday after upgrade to Qgis 2.15. I tried many things,but the only solution was to downgrade to the longterm release (LTR) version 2.8.8. It' working fine now I hope there is another solution, but this was the emergencial one for me now

Comment: 2.14 is much closer to 2.15 and given that 2.15 (nightly) is an option, the  reliability of an LTR should not be a requirement.

Comment: Which operating system/distribution are you using?

Comment: Thanks for comments all. Matthias: OS is xubuntu 15.10; apologies for omitting it in original post. Are you aware of any linux command which would print out all the versions of all the dependencies I have, which I could then compare against a required reference standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a recent ubuntu system like yours, the following command should work (I don't have ubuntu, so I cannot test)

```
sudo apt-get install python-future
```

on Fedora it's

```
sudo dnf install python-future
```

If this does not work you can also try

```
pip install future
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a know issue, reported at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14577

It's also discussed in http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-has-no-future-tc5258029.html where Jürgen suggests:

> The packages are thin wrappers around pip, that actually installs or uninstalls 
>   the package.  So they involve downloads from pypi - I guess it's a proxy issue 
>   that blocks that for you (%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/var/log/setup.log(.full) should have 
>   more details).

Comment: Thanks Anita. Looks like this is a live discussion so fingers crossed someone sorts it out at some point down the road - looks like Jurgen's going to. Cheers!