# QGIS 2.16 "Nødebo" libintl-8.dll missing

Tags: qgis, installation

I have some trouble to get the QGIS 2.16 32-bit installation working on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. When the installation is finished and I hit the QGIS Desktop 2.16.0 icon the next error pops up: "The program can't start because libintl-8.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

[image]

Reinstalling 2.16 didn't fix anything. Reinstalling 2.14.4 gave me the same result.

Comment: Maybe related: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new version of the installer out now named `QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.16.0-2-Setup-x86_64.exe`

It aims to install into `C:\Program files\QGIS 2.16.0`

This should fix all Nødebo-related errors.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my issue by just copying the file libintl-8.dll from an older version Lisbonia and pasting it into the Nodebo's bin...and it worked

Answer (score 1):

After I found out the QGIS Desktop 2.16.0 with GRASS 7.0.4 icon does work, I copy pasted all dll's from the Grass GIS bin to the QGIS bin. Now the QGIS Desktop 2.16.0 icon works as well!

Next I got a Python error: "Couldn't load QGIS utils. Python support will be disabled."

The answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202200/63260 by Tony Rowlands fixed that too:

"This has been reported as a bug on QGIS (bug number 15279). The reporter says: "the problem is the use of the character "ø" (o-slash) in the directory name for the QGIS program directory: "C:\Program Files\QGIS Nødebo". If you make a name change of the installation directory to ex. "C:\Program Files\QGIS Noedebo" it works without a hitch." I tried this by re-installing 2.16, with the directory name changed C:...to Noebedo..and 2.16 now works perfectly, including loading Python correctly."

Comment: @Matthias I think bug 15262 addresses the issue better.

Comment: @AndreJ I didn't introduce a new link to a bug :)

Comment: @AndreJ might do the job, thanks. But the default path in the Windows installer is "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Nødebo" and this is the source of the problems. The reason I posted this question / answer is to help other (less advance, like me) users find the solution.

Comment: Bug 15262 is exactly about missing libintl-8 (with the workaround you found), while bug 15279 reports missing qgis.core. I agree that the pathname is one reason, incorrect handling of utf8 encoded version names to filesystem-compliant folder names is the reason behind both bugs.